# Elmah Logging On Azure Worker Role?

Tags: azure, elmah, azure-worker-roles

Does anyone know how to configure Elamh for an Azure worker role? I've installed it but it doesn't seem to do anything - when exceptions occur they don't get logged. It works perfectly in my MVC project.

Is there any specific guidance for Azure worker role with Elamh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure Worker Roles have IIS disabled by default which means you can't use ELMAH.  You might have to try a more traditional logging approach.

On my most recent project, we decided to have our Worker Roles log to table storage and it works really well.  However, there have been some recent advancements since we first started that make logging much easier.

For more information, check out [Take Control of Logging and Tracing in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714589.aspx)

Comment: Makes sense. I saw someone mention in another post to use Elmah for Worker Role. I guess he was just wrong :)